# How can I get a follower count from the tiktok website?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

This is my first time ever writing a python script. I'm trying to pull a follower count from the tiktok website and use it as a string. I got the selector path from going into the Inspect window in chrome, clicking on the follower count, and right clicking "17M" (in this example) to save the selector path. This worked perfectly yesterday, and then all of the sudden it stopped and now I can't get the "17M" from this page no matter what I try. I'm using requests-html but would definitely try beautiful soup or whatever other recommendation you have!

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
url = "https://www.tiktok.com/@terrycrews"
r = session.get(url)
sel = '#main > div.jsx-2773227880.main-body.page-with-header.middle.em-follow > div.jsx- 2938571814.share-layout.compact.middle > div > header > h2.count-infos > div:nth-child(2) > strong'
followers = r.html.find(sel, first=True).text
print(followers)
```

The current error I get is
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
when I run this code. I'd expect to get `17M`.

I would love any help you might be able to provide. Thank you!

Comment: `.find` is returning the `None` object. Why it does that will depend upon what the value of `.html` is.

Answer (score 3):

Try to specify `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.tiktok.com/@terrycrews"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
print(soup.select_one('[title="Followers"]').text)
```

Prints:

```
17M
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! For some reason when I run this code, it still returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. It seems like there must be something else wrong on my end since both of these methods stopped working, and the former was working just fine yesterday.

Comment: It works for me.  Are you using his code exactly?  Using `requests` instead of `requests_html`?

Comment: Same code as above! when I type soup into the command line it returns a bunch of html code, but it doesn't seem to be complete because I can't find "Followers" when I scroll through it.

Comment: @David Make sure you haven't received Captcha page. Do `print(soup)` and search for `17M` or `Followers` there

Comment: Aha! I think you're right - I can't find 17M anywhere but I do see Captcha in the text - that makes so much sense!! Thank you! Now to figure out how to get around the captcha - I'm planning to run this script for a whole list of a couple thousand usernames to get follower counts, and I'd worry about running into the captcha partway through (or even how to get around it now to begin!)